# systemd-resolved returns server failure time to time

Tags: dns, systemd-resolved

One of my c++ app under 18.04 makes a lot http/s requests with libcurl. Later in logs I see such moaning: `CURL error has occurred: Couldn't resolve host name`.

Nearly the same in the syslog:

```
Jan 17 19:38:58 webserver systemd-resolved[22495]: Failed to start query: Invalid argument
Jan 17 19:38:58 webserver systemd-resolved[22495]: message repeated 34 times: [ Failed to start query: Invalid argument]
```

Settings:

```
danilabagroff@prx1:/tmp$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0
search central1.internal

danilabagroff@prx1:/tmp$ systemd-resolve --status
Global
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 2 (eth0)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 10.128.0.2 (cloud ns server)
          DNS Domain: central1.internal
```

I was listening `tcpdump -i lo -nn 'port 53' -w dns0.pcap` for a while and finally found out that **sometimes** I really received server failure but just for A record.

```
225 122.496707  127.0.0.1   127.0.0.53  DNS 88  Standard query 0x9a01 A mydomain.cloud OPT
226 122.496733  127.0.0.1   127.0.0.53  DNS 88  Standard query 0x720a AAAA mydomain.cloud OPT
227 122.496922  127.0.0.53  127.0.0.1   DNS 88  Standard query response 0x9a01 Server failure A mydomain.cloud OPT
228 122.497006  127.0.0.53  127.0.0.1   DNS 88  Standard query response 0x720a AAAA mydomain.cloud OPT
```

- the most strange thing to me: this is not happening always.
- no any server failures during `tcpdump`ing eth0

Please, share your thoughts ;)

Answer (score 1):

I'm experiencing same issue with libcurl and systemd-resolved under Ubuntu 18.04.4. Unfortunately, the only way that helps is restarting service once in a while:

```
sudo service systemd-resolved restart
```

Judging by line "central1.internal" in your config, I assume your machine is at Yandex Cloud?